# How do I remove ellipses from a stack trace in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to log a stack trace to SQL Server in C#.  Occasionally, I get a stack trace like this one:

> System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]:
>   A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP
>   Provider, error: 0 - The wait operation timed out.) (Fault Detail is
>   equal to An ExceptionDetail, likely created by
>   IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is:
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The wait
>   operation timed out.) ----> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The
>   wait operation timed out     --- End of inner ExceptionDetail stack
>   trace ---    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
>   newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
>   userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean
>   applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderMa...).

Notice the .. after SqlInternalConnectionTds and the ... after SqlAuthenticationProviderMa.  I'm not adding in the ellipses.  How do I get rid of this truncated text and get the FULL exception?

Thanks!

Comment: What code are you trying?

Comment: *"I get a stack trace"* - How are you getting that stack trace?

Comment: Note that `SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor` is correct. The `..ctor` is short form for the constructor of the `SqlInternalConnectionTds` class.

Comment: @GabrielLuci I am catching the exception in a catch block, and calling ToString() on it to get the text to log.  If the .. is correct, could you explain how I'm supposed to find out what the 'missing' text is?

Comment: Strictly speaking, only the second dot is part of the name. The first dot is a member separator. The "missing" text is the class name, which is on the other side of the member separator, so `SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor` refers to `SqlInternalConnectionTds.SqlInternalConnectionTds`.

Comment: There is no missing text in `SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor`. There is missing text at the end, after `SqlAuthenticationProviderMa`. Are you sure that your code that writes to your log isn't truncating it? You can look at [the code for `Exception.ToString()`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/exception.cs,438) and see that it does not truncate the stack trace. So it's happening after that.

Comment: @madreflection True!

Comment: You must be getting `Exception.Message`; typically I've seen `Object reference not set...").` this before, which in short, is a wrapped up short version of the actual error description. On the other hand, using `Exception.ToString()` guarantees the complete stack trace message.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ The `Message` doesn't contain the stack trace, but the output shown in the question shows a partial stack trace.

Comment: @GabrielLuci point taken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.  This issue only happens on FaultException objects.  I called the stack trace explicitly, and logged it.  Using this method, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to get a full stack trace is usually just to call ToString()

For example in MVC: 
File:

> /Shared/Error.cshtml

Code:

```
@model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo
<pre>
     @Model.Exception.ToString()
</pre>
```

Comment: That is what I'm doing.  I still get the ellipses.

Comment: Strange, I've been using this exact code for a long time, and never gotten the ... Are you sure you are outputing to a <pre> field that does not truncate the lenght?